# Running a script at startup in Linux?

Tags: linux, sh, daemon, startup, sudo

I have a script "mount.sh", is there any way I could run this at startup? Also, this involves using `sudo`, so when I try to run the script manually it asks for my password, is there a way to pass my password or bypass this altogether?

Comment: You cannot somehow bypass a manual password input, at least you certainly should not. Read about `sudo`: it allows you to setup an exception, a way to execute a very specific comment _without_ the requirement to input a password in an interactive manner.

Comment: Where exactly to place the command to be executed depends on your system, at least your distribution. You will have to add more details to your question.

Comment: For sudo, use root's cron tab http://askubuntu.com/questions/735935/running-command-at-startup-on-crontab